# Use of 'any' if 'not' is followed by a noun

Tags: grammar

So, I was watching [this video](https://unacademy.com/lesson/tense-present-indefinite-tense/T136WZFK) (jump to 6:00) where the instructor said: "If 'not' is followed by a noun then the use of 'any' is mandatory."
Does this mean "I do not write letters" is wrong and "I do not write any letters" is correct?
I am really confused.

Comment: In your example, "not" is followed by a verb "write".

Comment: @GEdgar That's the part of the confusion as well, but the instructor used the example I mentioned.

Comment: The instructor has not expressed herself clearly. She means that the noun following the negative verb form (_not write_, _not eat_, _not like_, etc.) must be preceded by _any_. I'm sorry, but this is simply wrong. _I do not write letters_ is perfectly grammatical, as is _They don't eat vegetables_ or _She doesn't like dogs_. That said, _any_ is often used with _not have_. _I don't have any friends_; _She doesn't have any brothers or sisters_, etc.

Comment: @Shoe You are right. I saw the video again and found her words confusing.  I will take your word. :)